# How to get JS and CSS file size on client side?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am automating a website test using Selenium Webdriver and Phantomjs (Casperjs).
I would like to do some performance check and as a part of it, I would like to check the size of the JS or CSS files (They should not exceed 40kb). I want to do this on client side.

I know that chrome dev tools or yslow shows me this information. So I would like to get the information from them if possible and easy, or just replicate whatever they are doing.

How can I do this?

Comment: do an ajax head request on the sheet/script URL and look at the content-length header, or load the whole thing and see the length of the response. Note that external sheets/scripts w/o CORS are not going to be measurable like this.

Comment: You can't use Selenium with PhantomJS **and** CasperJS. Please clarify what you actually use.

Comment: I am novice and I am writing tests using Selenium webdriver and PhamtomJS to automate the functional testcases for the site. I don't know what I should ideally use to test this part.

Comment: So you're saying that you accept solutions for Selenium+PhantomJS **and** PhantomJS+CasperJS? Also, please use `@replies` if you want to reply to someone. @deepng

Comment: @ArtjomB.yes, I am open to any suggestion. As I have said before I have no idea about the best way to deal with this.

Comment: @dandavis, I will try out your suggestion. Thank you.